# How to change the functionality of a lambda expression without assignment and composition?

Tags: python, lambda

Given the expression `f = lambda x: x+x` is it possible to edit the functionality of `f` by using a one line expression so that the following result will be achieved:

```
f(7) = 14
`the expression subtracts one from the return value of f`
f(7) = 13
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just reassign `f`, however, doing so in only one line will be tricky as you need to keep a reference to the old `lambda`:

```
old_f = f
f = lambda x: old_f(x) - 1
```

You can use a closure for this:

```
f = (lambda old_f: (lambda x: old_f(x) - 1))(f)
```

Comment: Nice, but the price you pay is probably a small performance hit compared to lamba x: x+x-1.

Comment: That was not a requirement ;). The performance hit is most likely of the order of 100%, since the function call is by far the dominating operation here, and for the modified `f` you are calling two functions (`f` and `old_f`).

Comment: Can you explain what is happening in scope level when this solution is used?

Comment: @Medvednic He is constructing a new lambda which internally holds the old lambda. So you cannot access the old lambda anymore but the new lambda can. Both is still in memory and both is used.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a default argument value to preserve the previous function via a closure and not need to introduce any new variable:

```
f = lambda x: x*2
print f(7)  # --> 14

f = (lambda prev_f=f: (lambda x: prev_f(x) - 1))(f)
print f(7)  # --> 13
```

Comment: Did you see the answer by filmor before? It seems very similar.

Comment: @Trilarion: Yes, I saw filmor's answer and it is similar but not exactly the same. The difference is that it doesn't require a separate `prev_f = f` statement beforehand, so it's truly a single line solution.